# unordered list number of list items

Tags: list, numbers, selenium-webdriver, unordered

I want find the numberof lis items (li) in html below:

```
<div class="li-control-block">
    <div class="inner">
        <a class="scroll-left" href="?slideId=7">
            <img width="59" height="30" alt="btn-hero-promo-slider-left" src="/c/images/btn-hero-promo-slider-left.png">
        </a>
        <ul class="slides-8">
            <li class="first">
                <a href="#">1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="">
                <a href="#">2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="">
                <a href="#">3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="">
                <a href="#">4</a>
            </li>
            <li class="">
                <a href="#">5</a>
            </li>
            <li class="">
                <a href="#">6</a>
            </li>
            <li class="">
                <a href="#">7</a>
            </li>
            <li class="last on">
        </ul>
            <a class="scroll-right" href="?slideId=1">
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried code below but that comes back with "12345678" which gives me size of 1.

So how can I get the size to be equal to 8 ?

```
List<WebElement> list=null;

    list = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".slides-8"));
    int length = list.size();
```

Comment: What tool/language are you using? Is this Selenium?

Comment: Is this a client or server side solution you are looking for, not sure I understand the technology being used.  Maybe try list.length();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing

```
WebElement temp = driver.findElement(By.classname("slides-8"));
List<WebElement> list = temp.findElement(By.xpath(".//li"));
System.out.println(list.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example works as expected; your code requests the number of elements which have a class of "slides-8", which is the list container.  Then you ask for how many elements that is, and it's one -- just one container.

Either apply a CSS class to each list element, or ask the container for the count of its elements.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using `cssSelectors` as well,

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".slides-8 > li"));
int length = list.size();
```